# Javascript injection through .NET App fails to find textarea

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

**UPDATE**

The error is coming through because the page is loading strangely -- is there a way you can tell your program to wait, while the page is still loading?

**END UPDATE**

I'm trying to inject some text into a textarea on a website through a .NET application using VB.NET. I have my browser control setup, but I'm having trouble with the javascript not finding the textarea.

I run this code using Chromes JScript Tricks extension, and it works perfectly.

```
document.getElementById('magicScanBox').value = '12345678\n12345679'
```

However, when I run the exact same script through my document, I get the error

```
Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run

```
Private Sub browser_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles browser.DocumentCompleted

    If browser.DocumentTitle = "Login" Then
        Dim headElement As HtmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
        Dim scriptElement As HtmlElement = browser.Document.CreateElement("script")
        Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement = DirectCast(scriptElement.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
        element.text = "document.getElementsByName('Username')[0].value='USERNAME';document.getElementsByName('Password')[0].value='PASSWORD';document.forms[0].submit();"
        headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement)
    End If

    If browser.DocumentTitle = "Inventory" Then
        Dim script = "document.getElementById('magicScanBox').value = '12345678\n12345679'"
        browser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", New Object() {script})

        'Dim headElement As HtmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
        'Dim scriptElement As HtmlElement = browser.Document.CreateElement("script")
        'Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement = DirectCast(scriptElement.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
        'element.text = "document.getElementById('magicScanBox').value = '12345678\n12345679';"
        'headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement)

    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that the top (`If browser.DocumentTitle = "Login"`) works fine. This injects the username/password and submits the form on the login page automatically.

I tried the same method with the part that is failing and it still isn't finding it. I have a suspicion that it's because it is a `textarea` control instead of a textbox, or something to do with how the browser control in VB.NET handles the injections.

How can I go about injecting a string into a `textarea` control with the following markup?

```
<textarea class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" style="resize: none;" rows="8" cols="10" id="magicScanBox" placeholder="" ng-paste="onPasteSerials($event)" ng-list="" ng-trim="false" ng-model="allEnteredSerials" ui-keypress="{13:'magicScan($event)'}"></textarea>
```

Also, just saying, I'm not able to edit the website or markup - It's another companies website that I'm trying to automate Inventory Upload to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the website reloads itself a few times, and so I ended up throwing a check in to see if the control I needed was loaded, and if it is, THEN go ahead and enter the information. If not, it uses a timer to wait until it's ready, and then fills it in.